# How to recursively create a string?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to build a string from a recursive routine, but the program stops when I call my function.

I'm using a dynamic structure to simulate a file manager. I want to show the actual working directory by going back (recursively) in the tree until I find the top and then return the actual name, and then concatenate it with the previous answer.

This is my code:

```
char *
getPath(lnodo *root, lnodo *actual)
{
    char resp[400];

    if (actual->pPA) {
        strcat(resp, getPath(root, actual));
        strcat(resp, "/");
        return resp;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(resp, actual->Nom);
        strcat(resp, "/");
        return resp;
    }
}

void
path(lnodo *root, lnodo *actual)
{
    printf("%s", getPath(root, actual));
}
```

The pointer `root` is the top of the tree. The pointer `actual` is the working directory. The member `Nom` of the struct is the name of the actual node, and the member `pPA` is the pointer to the parent of the actual node.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable. That returns a dangling pointer which you cannot use (without invoking *undefined behavior*)

Comment: C and C++ are **completely different languages**, so please tag what you're actually using. Throwing in unrelated tags creates a lot of clutter and confusion.

Comment: Also the `if(actual->pPA)` branch seems to recurse endlessly, since you never modify `actual->pPA` anywhere

Comment: Tip: You'll need to duplicate that buffer, or, better, push the responsibility for creating the buffer to the caller, as is tradition in C. `getPath(char* buf, size_t len, ...)`

Comment: Also, in `getPath`, you do: `strcat(resp, getPath(root, actual));`. This needs to be: `strcpy(resp, getPath(root, actual));` [because `resp` is uninitialized]. You did this correctly in the `else`. As others have mentioned `char resp[400];` is on the stack, so you'll have to fix that. You can do (e.g. `char *resp = malloc(400);` But, this will generate a lot of pointers that never get freed. So, it might be better to pass a pointer to the function, so that a single/final buffer is used.

Comment: Something like: `char * getPath(char *resp, lnodo *root, lnodo *actual) {  if (actual->pPA) { strcat(resp, getPath(resp, root, actual)); strcat(resp, "/"); } else { strcpy(resp, actual->Nom); strcat(resp, "/"); }  return resp; }  void path(lnodo *root, lnodo *actual) { char resp[10000]; resp[0] = 0; printf("%s\n", getPath(resp, root, actual)); }`

Comment: You may be interested in [painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).